# JSON date to NSDate and back

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdate

I have a JSON date, e.g: `1295804021525`, which is the number of milliseconds from 1970.

I have written the following code to convert this number into an NSDate:

```
long long seconds = [[payload valueForKey:@"starttime"]longLongValue]/1000;  
NSDate *somedate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
```

Which does work and returns the correct date. First I'm wondering if this is the best way of doing the conversion.

Next I am wondering how to convert back to the milliseconds format and then put into the url to send back to the server.

I have:

```
long long date = [somedate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl?since=%qi",date];
```

Again this seems to work but I was wondering how I could get the same functionality using NSNumber.

Comment: Do you need `-valueForKey:`? Why not `-objectForKey:` instead?

Comment: `payload` in this case is an `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`, however I'm curious as to what benefit this would bring? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With your original conversion, you're losing sub-second precision. You may want to do something like

```
CFTimeInterval seconds = [[payload valueForKey:@"starttime"] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
```

The second snippet should be fine.

I'm not sure why you think using NSNumber would help in any fashion. With the modification I mentioned, both these code snippets are straightforward and should work just fine.

Comment: I suppose in this context, `NSTimeInterval` may be slightly more semantically correct (as we're using NSDate), though the type itself is actually identical to `CFTimeInterval`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll try this tonight. I read somewhere about `NSNumber` being more platform independent than the primitive types it wraps, thats why I thought using it would be better?

Comment: Actually, forget that, I had read about `NSInteger` being different for different architecture types, not `NSNumber`.